# How to add build number to each jenkins image run?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to run the image that is built and pushed to Azure container registry. When I run the build again it is throwing error to replace the name to docker run. So, my question is how to add the build number with name of the container i,e. like --name "somename_buildnumber" for the below jenkinsfile to run the image. Can someone help me with this ?

```java
// Pull, Run, and Test on ACS 'stage'... 
          stage('ACS Docker Pull and Run') {
             app = docker.image('dockerregistry.azurecr.io/image:latest')
             docker.withRegistry('https://dockerregistry.azurecr.io', 'Credentails_ID') {
             app.pull()
               app.run('--name image_build_${env.BUILD_NUMBER} -i -t')
             }
          }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey.. you've modified your post in the meantime that let you look worse than before ;-) This makes my answer look a bit weird. Before, you had almost correctly `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` included in the `app.run()` call.

Comment: @StephenKing, no I changed it back. Your answer is spot on and it is working great...Thanks

Comment: I took the chance to once again modified it. I brought back the original single quotes, as otherwise your could would be already correct and any answers here would be nonsense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is Groovy's string interpolation, which is applied for double-quoted strings, but not for single-quoted ones.

Replace

```
app.run('--name pngimage_build_${env.BUILD_NUMBER} -i -t')
```

with

```
app.run("--name pngimage_build_${env.BUILD_NUMBER} -i -t")
```

and your variable will be replaced.